# How can I move variables into and out of a structure akin to LOAD and SAVE in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, save, structure, matlab-load

Is there a quick way (i.e. one line) to dump a collection of variables "in" a structure, using the variable names as the structure fields? The "load" function basically does this but saving and loading to a temporary file seems ugly.

For example:

```
clear
a = 'adsf'
b = rand(10);

x = var2struct(a,b)

x.a
x.b
```

or better yet:

```
x = var2struct(['a';'b'])
```

Also, what about the reverse (i.e. dumping the field values to the current scope as variables named after the fields)?:

```
clear
x.a='asdf'
x.b=rand(10);
dumpstruct(x)
a
b
```

Also, here's a related [newsgroup thread](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/289189).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aside from using [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) and [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html), there is no built-in function that I know of to do this. However, you could just make your own functions, like so:

```
function s = var2struct(varargin)
  names = arrayfun(@inputname,1:nargin,'UniformOutput',false);
  s = cell2struct(varargin,names,2);
end

function struct2var(s)
  cellfun(@(n,v) assignin('base',n,v),fieldnames(s),struct2cell(s));
end
```

Working from the base workspace, you can use these functions like so:

```
a = 'adsf'
b = rand(10);
x = var2struct(a,b);
clear a b
struct2var(x);
```

**A couple notes:**

- If you would rather specify the arguments to `var2struct` as the variable names instead of the variables themselves, here is an alternative function:

  ```
  function s = var2struct(varargin)
    values = cellfun(@(n) evalin('base',n),varargin,'UniformOutput',false);
    s = cell2struct(values,varargin,2);
  end
  ```

  And you would use this from the base workspace as follows:

  ```
  x = var2struct('a','b');
  ```

  Unfortunately, you can only use this version of the function to get variables from the base workspace, not the workspace of a function.
- One caveat with the `struct2var` function above is that it will always create the variables in the base workspace, not the workspace of the function calling `struct2var`. To create variables in a workspace other than the base, you would have to use this line in that workspace instead of calling `struct2var`:

  ```
  cellfun(@(n,v) assignin('caller',n,v),fieldnames(x),struct2cell(x));
  ```

Comment: Can't you use evalin('caller',n) for the second version of var2struct? Anyway, +1 for a beautiful solution that includes tons of advanced Matlab.

Comment: @Jonas: using `evalin('caller',n)` for the second version of `var2struct` would actually perform the evaluation in the function that calls `evalin`, which would be `var2struct` itself and not the function that calls `var2struct`. That's why I like the first version of `var2struct` better... it just seems cleaner and more versatile.

Comment: D'oh!. I remember now that I've made that mistake before.